# Tkinter Exception in Tkinter callback Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-requests, cjk

I'm trying to make an app that can creates anki decks of japanese, i already did have the code but i want to make an app with that code, and if you go to «Create Anki deck» enter the kanjis and the name file and press «Es» (now only works in spanish)  you get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/cristobal/Documentos/Programation/Python/Japanese/kanjiGraphics.py", line 255, in <lambda>
    self.languageButtons.append(tkinter.Button(self.window, text = i.capitalize(), bg = "#ffffff", fg = "#2c2c2c",bd = "3", highlightcolor = "#f5f5f5", font = font, command= lambda: self.WriteCalc(self.kanjisEntry[1].get("1.0", "end"), self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end"), kanji.GetKanjiMeaningsEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiReadingsEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiExpamplesEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiExampleReadingsEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiExampleMeaningEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")))))
  File "/home/cristobal/Documentos/Programation/Python/Japanese/kanji.py", line 282, in GetKanjiReadingsEs
    readings = paragraph[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I did `print(len(parapragh))` (paragraphs are of the page where the information of the japanese characters (kanjis) is stored) where i get the error and first i get 82, but it prints once more 0, maybe something of requests or idk :/

Also if you print `paragraph[0]` it works until `readings = paragraph[0]`

It could be something with the argument functions, because in this part i have to pass functions as arguments:

```
self.languageButtons.append(tkinter.Button(self.window, text = i.capitalize(), bg = "#ffffff", fg = "#2c2c2c",bd = "3", highlightcolor = "#f5f5f5", font = font, command= lambda: self.WriteCalc(self.kanjisEntry[1].get("1.0", "end"), self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end"), kanji.GetKanjiMeaningsEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiReadingsEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiExpamplesEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiExampleReadingsEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")), kanji.GetKanjiExampleMeaningEs(self.kanjisEntry[0].get("1.0", "end")))))
```

Here is the script that returns error
The function that returns error is GetKanjisReadingEs()

```
#Libraries
import webbrowser #This library open pages in your main web browser
import requests #This library get the html code of a page
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #This library prettify the html code


#Get Kanjis Meanings
def GetKanjiMeaningsEs(kanjis):
    allMeanings = []

    #Get the meaning of japanese character

    return allMeanings

#Get japanese characters readings
def GetKanjiReadingsEs(kanjis):

    allReadings = [] #The list where the readings will be stored
    for kanji in kanjis: #This for goes trough all the japanese characters you pass
        kanjiURL = f"https://japonesbasico.com/kanji/{kanji}" #The link
        kanjiRequest = requests.get(kanjiURL) #Get the page from the link

        soup = BeautifulSoup(kanjiRequest.text, "html.parser") #Get the html code of the page

        paragraph = soup.select("p") #Get all the elements with <p> tag in soup

        print(len(paragraph)) #This print for no reason prints twice, first 83 and second 0 (i think this is why index out of range)
        
        readings = paragraph[0].text #Get the first <p> tag what always is the readings #Here i get the error

        end = readings.find("Lecturas japonesas") #Get the value where it has to stop

        chineseReadings = "" #Where the chinese reading (onyomi) of the character will be stored
        japaneseReadings = "" #Where the japanese reading (kunyomi) of the character will be stored
        
        e = 0 #This is a counter
        for i in readings: 
            if e > len("Lecturas chinas") and e < end: #Get the characters between the word chinese readings and the word japanese readings
                chineseReadings += i
            e += 1

        e = 0
        for i in readings:
            if e >= end + len("Lecturas japonesas: "): #Get the characters between the word japanese readings and the end
                japaneseReadings += i 
            e += 1

        allReadings.append([chineseReadings, japaneseReadings]) #Add the readings of one kanji, more kanjis more elements

    return allReadings

#Get words with the kanjis
def GetKanjiExpamplesEs(kanjis):
    allExamples = []

    #Get examples of japanese characters

    return allExamples

def GetKanjiExampleReadingsEs(kanjis):
    allExampleReadings = []

    #Get the reading (how to read) the examples

    return allExampleReadings

#Get example words meaning with the notes (the parentesis after the reading) of the kanji
def GetKanjiExampleMeaningEs(kanjis):
    allExampleMeanings = []

    #Get the meaning of the examples

    return allExampleMeaning
```

Here is the 'tkinter' part of my code: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/ilinonugum.rb

Here is the code that get information of japanese characters: https://paste.pythondiscord.com/kotapiwosi.py

Here is the code that runs the app (only instatiate the class): https://paste.pythondiscord.com/imuvuyikoy.py

Comment: Please define a normal function instead of the `lambda`. There is absolutely no way anyone will be able to read and understand that ling line of code. Also please provide more code. I have no idea what `self.kanjisEntry` is.

Comment: Sorry but i already have a function what is «WriteCalc» and it requires all those arguments, i don't know how to make it more readable. Also added the tkinter code but stackoverflow doesn't let me puto more so i put other links for all the code.

Comment: There is a reason why stackoverflow doesn't allow you to put that much code. No one will want to read all of it. Also if your code isn't readable (if you have very long lines of code), it will be very hard to debug. Please try simplifying the code as much as possible.

Comment: I already simplified the script that returns the error and commented it, i hope you can understand if don't please tell me ;-;

Comment: Now the code look way better. Try adding `kanjis = kanjis.strip("\n")` to the start of the `GetKanjiReadingsEs`. I think the problem comes from `kanjisEntry.get("1.0", "end")` where tkinter adds a new line at the end. That confuses the website and gives you don't get the html you expected. Also you can always just have an if statement and check `if len(paragraph) > 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231296/discussion-between-patitotective-and-thelizzard).